# Can we have soft shadows using Aframe?

Tags: html, render, shadow, aframe

I'm trying to have a better render on my scene. So I added directional and ambiant lights. So Shadows are generated. Here's the 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFJEJ.jpg)

I wonder if there is a way to have softer shadows.
The model has been created with Sweet Home : http://www.sweethome3d.com/

Answer (score 1):

On the scene element, you could try to change the default type of the shadows:

`<a-scene shadow="type: pcfsoft">`

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/shadow.html#scene_properties_type

Also worth experimenting with the properties on the light itself:

> 3. Adjust the shadow camera position and frustum (shadowCameraTop, shadowCameraRight, …) of the directional light, until it envelops the scene tightly. If the frustum is too small, shadows will be missing or partially clipped. If the frustum is too large, shadows will appear coarse or pixelated

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/light.html#adding-real-time-shadows

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/light.html#configuring-shadows

Comment: Gotta check it out, I wanted to suggest lightmapping, or texture baking, but this is great !

Comment: Well actually, I tried Texture baking but I just couldn't have it like I want. The shadow is baked into the ground texture but the ground texture itself changed. I used Blender to do it and... It was a hard time ^^
I've also tried changing the shadow itself and the lights properties but the shadow edge did not change.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn up the ambient light to change the shadow color.
2. Play with `light.shadowRadius` property (currently master branch of A-Frame). And decrease shadow map resolution.
3. `<a-scene shadow="type: pcfsoft">`

Comment: Thanks ! I modified the shadowCamera field ( I think that is what you meant by light.shadowradius). It 's been better ; but I think I'll go on texture baking to have someting more sharp and "realistic"

Comment: There's a `light.shadowRadius` property on master branch of A-Frame. Texture baking look better, yeah, for non-dynamic stuff.